# Automatically recompile service project when updating service reference

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio

We have a solution (called, say, `Cabbage`) that's split up into a WCF-based backend (`Cabbage.Backend`), and a frontend (`Cabbage.Frontend`). A problem that crops up somewhat often is that a developer changes the definition of a WCF service in `Cabbage.Backend`, then updates the service reference in `Cabbage.Frontend` **without** first rebuilding `Cabbage.Backend`. (The services are meant to be tightly coupled this way, the layers are only separated by WCF to let us deploy backend hotfixes quicker.) This regenerates the service client based on a random old build instead of the current state of the source code, the BE dev calls it a day, hilarious merge conflicts occur when the FE dev updates the client himself.

Is there any way to make Visual Studio automatically rebuild the service project / the whole solution before every run of Update Service Reference to avoid this?

Comment: Your developers should never be committing code that hasn't been compiled and had all tests run against it.  Using a continuous build process that deploys "stable" libraries which would be the ones that the front-end developers would grab would also solve this.

Comment: @MikeParkhill "shouldn't" != "won't". We had to hit the ground running with this project with a head count of one dev with experience except not in processes, an intern, and me having recently switched from Java. Setting all that stuff up is waiting for that mythical When There's (tm) time.

Answer (score 1):

If you can suffer a longer build time then consider adding a project dependency on the backend to the frontend project. When you build the frontend, the backend and all of its dependencies will also build.

Comment: That's also what I came up with in my projects, which case is even worse because there are even more layers ;) I don't think that there is another solution: it is the responsibility of the back-end project to know its dependencies, not the other way around. Unfortunately this doesn't apply when you hit "Update Service Reference" :/